# View results of Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, view

I have a stored procedure that executes a dynamically built string.

It unions several select statements from a constantly changing schema on another server I have no control over (hence the dynamic string). I want to be able to access the results of this procedure from a view, but this is where I get stuck.

I created a stored procedure (code below) which outputs my results to a table, but I want to be able to perform joins, etc. so it would be really convenient if there was some way to wrap this into a view- I'm thinking a table valued function, but I haven't quite figured out how to get the dynamic SQL into a function... any help is appreciated!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]
 AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql+'

','')+'SELECT TOP (900) *
                                   FROM   OPENQUERY(Linked_Server, 
                                                  'SELECT   col1, col2, col3

FROM dbo.'+  tableName+'
               +'
               UNION' FROM  dbo.ls_views

--dbo.ls_views is a view with the pertinent views/table names from the other server.

Set @sql = @sql+ '
Select top (0) ''1'', ''2'',''3'' from sys.tables '           
--last select statement is to end multiple unions... not sure if there is a better way, but this works.

    --PRINT (@sql);
        --EXEC  (@sql);
EXECUTE sp_Executesql @sql
    GO
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Marc, you're right.  I got in a rush replacing my code with 'dummy' code.

Comment: Since you are already using linked servers, you can retrieve the results by using OPENQUERY when you execute the stored procedure: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Linked_Server, 'EXEC [dbo].[usp_test]')`

Answer (score 0):

Can you have SQL Agent execute this periodically and dump the results into another table/set of tables in your db?

Then you could use it as a straight join in whatever query you want.

Comment: I thought about this, but the underlying parts change frequently, so I really want to access the 'live' data. This is, indeed, my backup plan.

Comment: How frequently does a Db schema change?

Comment: It varies, sometimes not at all for several hours, then perhaps several times over a few minutes.  If there isn't a way to access it dynamically, I will schedule a SQL agent job to periodically dump the results to a table.